# Migration to another server cause problem with home page

Tags: joomla-3.x

I have migrated my Joomla site from a shared host to a dedicated server.
In the shared host I was using Cpanel(root directory:public_html) and in the dedicated server I´m using Plesk(root directory:httpdocs).
Both Linux servers.

I made the migration with akeeba component, and everything seems to be alright except the home page. All the other links seem to work, and the administrative area also.

The only problem is that I can not access my site from mysite.com, redirects to a default plesk page.
 However if I add index.php to the url the page will load. eg: www.mysite.com/index.php
But with this way I lose the SEO friendly fixture.

My Joomla version - 3.7.0
PHP - 5.6.30 (in both servers)

And this is what I have in the .httacess file:

```
##
# @package    Joomla
# @copyright  Copyright (C) 2005 - 2017 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license    GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems with some server configurations.
# It is required for the use of mod_rewrite, but it may have already been set by your
# server administrator in a way that disallows changing it in this .htaccess file.
# If using it causes your site to produce an error, comment it out (add # to the
# beginning of the line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef urls. If
# they work, then it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need to
# set it here.
##

## No directory listings
<IfModule autoindex>
  IndexIgnore *
</IfModule>

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site then comment out the operations listed
# below by adding a # to the beginning of the line.
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` on Joomla!
#
# Block any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root home page
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment the following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

# RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

Someone have idea of ​​what to do in this situation?
Any help would be appreciated.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

Connect with FTP or through your Plesk File Manager and see if there is any default index.html file by the plesk server.

I guess this is what gets loaded, instead of your index.php and that's why you see the plesk page.

I would also suggest to instruct your server for the files execution order, so to parse first index.php vs index.html

You can do so in your .htaccess file

```
#File execution order
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

Comment: Yes, I have a error_docs folder with many html pages. But I tried the DirectoryIndex index.php index.html that u told but without sucess. Everything still the same.

Comment: @legolax if there is an index.html file in your document root, remove it...

Comment: ty for ur help, but I just solved the problem adding DirectoryIndex index.php to the .htacess file.

Comment: @legolax, This is what I am suggesting you on my answer. Also go and remove the index.html file from the document root - it';s the index.html of from plesk account profile and you don't need it.